# Count integers up to n that contain the digits 2018 in order

Tags: algorithm, integer, digits, subsequence

Given an integer *n* between 0 and 10,0000,0000, count the number  of integers smaller than *n* which contain the digits [2,0,1,8] in order.

So e.g. the number 9,230,414,587 should be counted, because removing the digits [9,3,4,4,5,7] leaves us with [2,0,1,8].

Example input and output:

```
n = 2018      ->  count =     1
n = 20182018  ->  count = 92237
```

My general thought is that: the maximum length of *n* is 10 and the worst situation is that we have to insert 6 digits into  [2,0,1,8] and remove the duplicates and the numbers greater than *n*.

Comment: I'm sorry, this sounds like an interesting question but I am a little unclear on what exactly you want the algorithm to do. How did you get `92237` for the output of the `20182018` number?

Comment: @Alerra  sorry  for the late  explanation,`92237` Is the numbers of the all numbers which `< 20182018(n) ` .such as `20182017\20182016\20182014` This all < `20182018(n)` and find the numbers of the number meet the need.

Comment: In a word,count the number which `< n` and  meet the need!

Comment: So, why does `20182015` not work but `20182016` and `20182014` do work? I'm sorry I am still confused by this.

Comment: @Alerra uh..I just miss type it - -,it is some example.I update the description about how to define `2018` number.And what the algorithm do is to count the `2018` Number which < n

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, we want to count the number of different numbers `< n` such that `2018` is contained in the digits of these numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179346/discussion-between-ileadall42-and-alerra).

Comment: Do you know dynamic programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any own attempts to solve, so I'll give only clue:

You have 9-digits number (small numbers might be represented as 000002018) containing digit sequence 2,0,1,8.
Name them 'good' ones.
Let denote digit places from 1 to 9 right to left:

```
     number     532705183
digits     5  3  2  7  0  5  1  8  3
index      9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

The most left '2' digit can occupy places from 4 to 9. How many good numbers contain the first `2` at k-th place? Let make function `F2(l, k)` for quantity of good numbers where 2 refers to digit `2`, l is number length, k is place for the most left digit.

```
 .   .   .   .  2   .   .   .   .
                ^ 
                | 
 left part      k     right part should contain 0 1 8 sequence
 without 2's

 F2(9, k) = 9^(9-k) * Sum(F0(k-1, j) for j=1..k-1)
```

Overall quantity of good numbers is sum of `F2(9, k)` for all possible k.

```
GoodCount = Sum(F2(9, k) for k=4..9)
```

Explanation:

There are 9-k places at the left. We can put any digit but 2 there, so there are 9^(9-k) possible left parts.

Now we can place `0` at the right part and count possible variants for `018` subsequences. `F0(...)` will of course depend on `F1(...)` and `F1` will depend on `F8(...)` for shorter numbers.

So fill tables for values for `F8, F0, F1` step-by-step and finally calculate result for digit 2.

Hand-made example for 4-digit numbers containing subsequence `1 8` and `k` = position of the first '1':
k=2: there are 81 numbers of kind `xx18`
k=3: there are numbers of kind `x1x8` and `x18x`
there are 9 subnumbers like `x8`, 10 subnumbers `8x`, so (10+9)*9=171
k=4: there are numbers of kind
`1xx8` (9*9=81 such numbers),
`1x8x` (9*10=90 numbers),
`18xx` (100 numbers),
so 81+90+100=271
Overall: 81+171+271=523

Comment: Thanks for your answers to,but your answer get a little complicated to undestand,still thanks for your time .I still fail to undestand the `F` function .

Comment: I slightly rewrote my answer

Comment: I get it !You define a way how to caculate the final result.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a relatively *small* problem set. If the numbers were much bigger, I'd opt to use optimised techniques to just generate all numbers that meet your criteria (those containing the digits in that order) rather than generating *all* possible numbers and *checking* each to ensure it meets the criteria.

However, the brute force method does your `20182018` variant in about ten seconds and the full `1,000,000,000` range in a little under eight minutes.

So, unless you need it faster than that, you may find the brute-force method more than adequate:

```
import re

num = 1000000000 # or 20182018 or something else.

lookfor = re.compile("2.*0.*1.*8")
count = 0
for i in range(num + 1):
    if lookfor.search(str(i)) is not None:
        count += 1
        #print(count, i) # For checking.
print(count)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,and I do want to find a faster method!